# visual studio code remote ssh over ssh proxy

Tags: ssh, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging

I am trying to use vs-code's [remote-ssh extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh) to connect to a server over a ssh tunnel.
The server is part of an internal cluster that does not have a public ip address, and I connect to it via a proxy in the cluster using the method outlined in [link](https://backreference.org/2010/02/26/jump-in-with-ssh-and-netcat/):

```
# ~/.ssh/config
Host internal*
User root
ProxyCommand ssh user@firewall 'nc %h %p'
```

When I try to connect to the internal server, I get the following error dialog:

> Could not establish connection to "internal-server". The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.

The output window's log:

```
remote-ssh@0.45.6
win32 x64
SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+internal-server", attempt 1
SSH Resolver called for host: internal-server
Setting up SSH remote "internal-server"
Using commit id "........" and quality "stable" for server
Testing ssh with ssh -V
ssh exited with code: 0
Got stderr from ssh: OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5
Running script with connection command: ssh -o ClearAllForwardings=true internal-server bash
Install and start server if needed
> 
Got some output, clearing connection timeout
> ]0;C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\cmd.exe
> 
> CreateProcessW failed error:2
> 
> posix_spawn: No such file or directory
> The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
> 
"install" terminal command done
Install terminal quit with output: The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
Received install output: The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe
TELEMETRY: {"eventName":"resolver","properties":{"outcome":"failure","reason":"OfflineError"},"measures":{"resolveAttempts":1,"retries":1}}
------
```

How can I use vs-code's remote-ssh to connect to computers behind a proxy/firewall?

Answer (score 10):

For anyone running into the same problem, I solved it by giving the absolute location of ssh, eg:

```
ProxyCommand C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe -W %h:%p server
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Thanks for your help, this solved my issue! Windows needed to know where my ProxyCommand was for some reason X_x.

Comment: Where do I add it? In the remote ssh config?

Answer (score 0):

There can be two reasons till now which I've explored.

1. You are facing this error because of misconfiguration/conflict in/of your ssh file. What worked for me is , I am having directory "C:\Users\gur51262" which is having ssh configuration but there is another directory also which is having file "ssh_config" on path "C:\ProgramData\ssh" which is may be creating conflict with it .

So I have only configured file which is present on this path "C:\Users\gur51262" and I've omitted the content of other file which is present on path "C:\ProgramData\ssh".

Also make sure you are following syntax of config file , if there is any. Like

```
Host host203
  HostName 172.19.51.203
  User root
```

**Solution is for windows7.**

2. There are chances of conflicts in ".ssh/config" file. There may be a duplicate entry of hostname , like below

   > ```
   > Host 172.19.51.212
   >   HostName 172.19.51.212
   > Host 172.19.51.212
   >   HostName 172.19.51.212
   >   User root
   > ```