# rm: cannot remove ‘.vscode-server/bin/xxxxxx/.nfs000000000xxxxxxxxxxxx’: Device or resource busy

Tags: visual-studio-code

the problem occurred after removing visual code studio (vscode) remote ssh from the client. By uninstalling Remote SSH in an attempt was done to free up memory taken on host computer.

Answer (score 3):

I learnt that the folder under .vscode_server/ have two subfolder and I wanted to remove the folder since the some extentions was taking too much space, it was

> **rm -rf .vscode-server/**

```bash
rm: cannot remove ‘.vscode-server/bin/c47d83b293181d9be64f27ff093689e8e7aed054/.nfs000000000428ac6a000005ce’: Device or resource busy
rm: cannot remove ‘.vscode-server/bin/c47d83b293181d9be64f27ff093689e8e7aed054/.nfs0000000006b42642000005f6’: Device or resource busy
rm: cannot remove ‘.vscode-server/bin/c47d83b293181d9be64f27ff093689e8e7aed054/.nfs0000000006c122f3000005fe’: Device or resource busy
rm: cannot remove ‘.vscode-server/bin/c47d83b293181d9be64f27ff093689e8e7aed054/.nfs000000000609731e00000607’: Device or resource busy
rm: cannot remove ‘.vscode-server/bin/c47d83b293181d9be64f27ff093689e8e7aed054/.nfs000000000154ec5400000623’: Device or resource busy
rm: cannot remove ‘.vscode-server/bin/c47d83b293181d9be64f27ff093689e8e7aed054/.nfs00000000015e1f560000062d’: Device or resource busy
rm: cannot remove ‘.vscode-server/bin/c47d83b293181d9be64f27ff093689e8e7aed054/.nfs0000000007fa221c00000632’: Device or resource busy
rm: cannot remove ‘.vscode-server/bin/c47d83b293181d9be64f27ff093689e8e7aed054/.nfs00000000011f979d00000643’: Device or resource busy
```

```bash
cd .vscode-server/

ls

bin/ extensions/

cd extensions

ls

ms-vscode.cpptools-0.26.3

cd ms-vscode.cpptools-0.26.3

ls

bin

ls

.nfs0000000005615fa900000b1b* .nfs0000000005615faa00000b1c*

rm -rf .nfs0000000005615fa900000b1b 

rm: cannot remove ‘.nfs0000000005615fa900000b1b’: Device or resource busy

lsof .nfs0000000005615fa900000b1b** 

COMMAND     PID    USER  FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME

Microsoft   966 xxxxxx txt    REG   0,40 14250189 90267561 .nfs0000000005615fa900000b1b

Microsoft  1145 xxxxxx txt    REG   0,40 14250189 90267561 .nfs0000000005615fa900000b1b

Microsoft  1642 xxxxxx txt    REG   0,40 14250189 90267561 .nfs0000000005615fa900000b1b
```

**.... many line here ....**

Here I used notepad++ to kill all sub-process running

```bash
kill -9 966

kill -9 1145

kill -9 1642
```

**... etc**

so finally the process .nfs0000000005615fa900000b1b was removed

you need to that for all process but start from the subprocesses. I am sure some genius will do this effectively and fast. But I was happy that I finally could get rid of .vscode-server folder.

Hope this was helpful!

Answer (score 3):

I used

```
ps -aux | grep vscode
```

to find and kill all the processes associated with vscode. Then I deleted the folder with `rm -rf ~/.vscode-server`

Answer (score 0):

You may also try

```
kill -u <username>  # Beware while using this command. It will stop other processes too.
rm -rf .vscode-server/
```