# The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh

I am trying to connect to my schools virtual server through vscode. I have configured the config file with the proper information. Occasionally I can connect to the server using PuTTY but vscode always gives me issues from "Architecture not being supported" to "resource being temporarily unavailable". I have tried uninstalling VScode and reinstalling, uninstalling OpenSSH and reinstalling and connecting through SSH on cmd. I would appreciate some assistance with any of this. Thanks!

[Remote settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vITk1.png)

```
[12:47:48.394] remote-ssh@0.55.0
[12:47:48.394] win32 x64
[12:47:48.395] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+bertvm", attempt 1
[12:47:48.395] SSH Resolver called for host: bertvm
[12:47:48.395] Setting up SSH remote "bertvm"
[12:47:48.430] Using commit id "2af051012b66169dde0c4dfae3f5ef48f787ff69" and quality "stable" for server
[12:47:48.431] Install and start server if needed
[12:47:48.434] Checking ssh with "ssh -V"
[12:47:48.473] > OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5

[12:47:48.478] Using SSH config file "C:\Users\Work\.ssh\config"
[12:47:48.478] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 50738 -F "C:\Users\Work\.ssh\config" bertvm bash
[12:47:48.481] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[12:47:48.572] > 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> ]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[12:47:48.572] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[12:47:48.580] > 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
[12:47:48.940] > rruiz30@bertvm.cs.uic.edu's password: 
[12:47:48.941] Showing password prompt
[12:47:52.122] Got password response
[12:47:52.122] "install" wrote data to terminal: "**********"
[12:47:52.133] > 
> 
[12:47:55.126] > exec request failed on channel 2
> 
[12:47:55.134] > The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
> 
[12:47:55.430] "install" terminal command done
[12:47:55.430] Install terminal quit with output: The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
[12:47:55.430] Received install output: The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
[12:47:55.435] Resolver error: Error: The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe
    at Function.Offline (c:\Users\Work\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.55.0\out\extension.js:1:130625)
    at c:\Users\Work\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.55.0\out\extension.js:1:126609
    at Object.t.handleInstallOutput (c:\Users\Work\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.55.0\out\extension.js:1:126987)
    at I (c:\Users\Work\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.55.0\out\extension.js:127:106775)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
    at async c:\Users\Work\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.55.0\out\extension.js:127:104774
    at async Object.t.withShowDetailsEvent (c:\Users\Work\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.55.0\out\extension.js:127:109845)
    at async Object.t.resolve (c:\Users\Work\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.55.0\out\extension.js:127:107960)
    at async c:\Users\Work\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.55.0\out\extension.js:127:141955
[12:47:55.438] ------




[12:52:41.444] Picking SSH host
[12:53:14.509] Picking SSH host
[12:53:15.251] Selected bertvm
```

I am now getting this error after clearing out the settings for Remote.ssh: Remote Platform

```
[13:16:51.543] Log Level: 2
[13:16:51.574] remote-ssh@0.55.0
[13:16:51.574] win32 x64
[13:16:51.575] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+bertvm", attempt 1
[13:16:51.575] SSH Resolver called for host: bertvm
[13:16:51.575] Setting up SSH remote "bertvm"
[13:16:51.640] Using commit id "2af051012b66169dde0c4dfae3f5ef48f787ff69" and quality "stable" for server
[13:16:51.641] Install and start server if needed
[13:16:52.807] Checking ssh with "ssh -V"
[13:16:52.844] > OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5

[13:16:52.847] Using SSH config file "C:\Users\Work\.ssh\config"
[13:16:52.848] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 56680 -F "C:\Users\Work\.ssh\config" bertvm bash
[13:16:52.849] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[13:16:52.949] > 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> ]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[13:16:52.949] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[13:16:52.959] > 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
[13:16:53.310] > rruiz30@bertvm.cs.uic.edu's password: 
[13:16:53.310] Showing password prompt
[13:16:55.934] Got password response
[13:16:55.935] "install" wrote data to terminal: "**********"
[13:16:55.948] > 
> 
[13:16:59.504] > d43eec630a6b: running
> 
[13:16:59.538] > bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
> 
[13:17:00.549] > bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
> 
[13:17:02.548] > bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
> 
[13:17:06.547] > bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
> 
[13:17:14.550] > bash: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
> 
[13:17:14.559] > Unsupported architecture: 
> d43eec630a6b##27##        
> 
[13:17:14.559] Received install output: d43eec630a6b##27##
[13:17:14.559] Unsupported architecture
[13:17:14.564] Resolver error: Error: The remote host's architecture is not supported
    at Function.ExitCode (c:\Users\Work\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.55.0\out\extension.js:1:130495)
    at Object.t.handleInstallOutput (c:\Users\Work\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.55.0\out\extension.js:1:128380)
    at I (c:\Users\Work\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.55.0\out\extension.js:127:106775)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
    at async c:\Users\Work\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.55.0\out\extension.js:127:104774
    at async Object.t.withShowDetailsEvent (c:\Users\Work\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.55.0\out\extension.js:127:109845)
    at async Object.t.resolve (c:\Users\Work\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.55.0\out\extension.js:127:107960)
    at async c:\Users\Work\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.55.0\out\extension.js:127:141955
[13:17:14.567] ------




[13:17:15.073] "install" terminal command done
[13:17:15.074] Install terminal quit with output:
```

Comment: Possible duplicate issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60335069/vscode-remote-connection-error-the-process-tried-to-write-to-a-nonexistent-pipe

Comment: I'm having the same issue