# Could not establish connection to "hostname". (Remote-SSH problem in VSCode ) (CentOS7)

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, remote-server

**[SOLVED!!]**

- **Server OS:** CentOS Linux 7
- **VSCode version (local):** 1.59.1

I connected to my server by ssh

```
ssh ...@ln01.twcc.ai
```

I try to open VSCode by local, and using **Remote-SSH -> Connected to SSH -> type ...@ln01.twcc.ai**

Then got **Could not establish connection to "@ln01.twcc.ai".** Error block
and output is like as below

```
[11:37:51.572] Log Level: 2
[11:37:51.574] remote-ssh@0.65.7
[11:37:51.574] win32 x64
[11:37:51.575] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+...", attempt 1
[11:37:51.575] "remote.SSH.useLocalServer": false
[11:37:51.575] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[11:37:51.575] "remote.SSH.remotePlatform": {}
[11:37:51.575] "remote.SSH.path": undefined
[11:37:51.575] "remote.SSH.configFile": undefined
[11:37:51.575] "remote.SSH.useFlock": true
[11:37:51.576] "remote.SSH.lockfilesInTmp": false
[11:37:51.576] "remote.SSH.localServerDownload": auto
[11:37:51.576] "remote.SSH.remoteServerListenOnSocket": false
[11:37:51.576] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[11:37:51.576] "remote.SSH.defaultExtensions": []
[11:37:51.576] "remote.SSH.loglevel": 2
[11:37:51.576] SSH Resolver called for host: ssh ...@ln01.twcc.ai
[11:37:51.576] Setting up SSH remote "ln01.twcc.ai"
[11:37:51.592] Using commit id "..." and quality "stable" for server
[11:37:51.595] Install and start server if needed
[11:37:56.696] Checking ssh with "ssh -V"
[11:37:56.726] > OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2

[11:37:56.729] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 53574 "ssh ...@ln01.twcc.ai" bash
[11:37:56.731] Terminal shell path: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
[11:37:56.948] > ]0;C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
[11:37:56.948] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[11:37:57.376] > 

[11:37:59.421] > ssh ...@ln01.twcc.ai: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with
> -mic,keyboard-interactive).
[11:37:59.434] > 程序嘗試寫入到一個不存在的管道。
[11:38:00.713] "install" terminal command done
[11:38:00.714] Install terminal quit with output: 程序嘗試寫入到一個不存在的管道。
[11:38:00.714] Received install output: 程序嘗試寫入到一個不存在的管道。
[11:38:00.714] Failed to parse remote port from server output
[11:38:00.715] Resolver error: Error: 
    at Function.Create (c:\Users\ASUS\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.7\out\extension.js:1:64659)
    at Object.t.handleInstallOutput (c:\Users\ASUS\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.7\out\extension.js:1:63302)
    at Object.t.tryInstall (c:\Users\ASUS\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.7\out\extension.js:1:415135)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async c:\Users\ASUS\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.7\out\extension.js:1:294918
    at async Object.t.withShowDetailsEvent (c:\Users\ASUS\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.7\out\extension.js:1:406463)
    at async Object.t.resolve (c:\Users\ASUS\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.7\out\extension.js:1:295994)
    at async c:\Users\ASUS\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.7\out\extension.js:127:110656
[11:38:00.718] ------
```

---

**Summary**

- When I try to remote-ssh by local VSCode, got the **Disconnected from SSH** Error

[Error Block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gb4lG.jpg)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to delete the fingerprint (a single line that corresponds to this particular connection - not the whole file) saved within the **known_hosts** file. If in Windows, this is placed at `C:\Users\<your_user_name>\.ssh\known_host` whereas for Linux that would be within `/home/<your_user_name>/.ssh/known_hosts` dir.

Since more detailed, you may also want to check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60335069/vscode-remote-connection-error-the-process-tried-to-write-to-a-nonexistent-pipe) too.

Answer (score 10):

Here is what worked for me:

1. Open the command panel on VS code (`Ctrl+Shift+P` for Windows and `Cmd+Shift+P` for Mac).
2. Search for `Kill VS Code Server on Host`, click it - it will be automatically deleted.
3. Reload VS Code and establish connection again.

For more details, please visit [here](https://support.huaweicloud.com/intl/en-us/modelarts_faq/modelarts_05_3119.html).

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by writing SSH config files first before remoting.

If you connected to server by ssh like:

```
ssh Amy@123.456.78.999 -p 22
```

Then config file would be:

```
Host MyHostName
    HostName 123.456.78.999
    User Amy
    Port 22
```

reference: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/3968

Comment: this solved the issue for me -- specifically adding the port number to the config file

I've been using remote SSH for two years now and until now it was fine, no update or anything that would explain what changed...

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem turned out to be that there was no free disk space on the server (also logs in vscode were different).

Disk usage can be checked with:
`df -h`

Answer (score 0):

If `Kill VS Code Server on Host` won't help (after you have tried that!), then make a refresh on local machine by:

1. Delete `~/.vscode`
2. Delete `~/.config/Code`

Then re-install the latest version of VSCode. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Yea I was also facing same issue when I updated my VS code to latest version 1.75.1
Facing issue "Connection failed XSH issue"

This is because of proxy issue with you linux machine where your VS code is trying to connect .

Solution:

1. 'Navigate to Linux machine--> and perform below operation
   [user @linuxmachineip] : cd .vs code-server/    (navigate to vs code-sever folder)
2. [user @linuxmachineip .vs code-server] : SU -     (login as Root user)
3. [user @linuxmachineip .vs code-server] : cd / etc / profile.d    (navigate to etc/profile.d folder)
4. [user@linuxmachineip .vscode-server] : mv proxy.sh.off proxy.sh (rename proxy.sh.off to proxy.sh  ***** as this will enable your vscode to connect to internet to download all necessary files in profile.d folder )
5. Now relaunch your VS code and try to connect . (it will connect now)
   And then again come back to Linux machine
6. [user@linuxmachineip .vscode-server] mv proxy.sh proxy.sh.off (rename proxy.sh to proxy.sh.off  ***** as this will disable again)'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had to add `PowerShell` to system path on the machine I was trying to connect to. You can quickly check if you need to do this by typing `PowerShell` in `cmd` on that machine, if you get an error like `PowerShell` is not recognized as an internal or external command" then add this variable to path `%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\`

Where you replace `%SYSTEMROOT%` with the path to right before `system32` on that machine.

[How to add to path.](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94933-how-do-i-edit-my-system-path-in-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Adding new remote host with same properties worked for me

Answer (score -2):

I have faced the problem many times. Restart the vscode program always resolve my problem.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33479140)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).