# Remove fingerprint on vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh

I was trying to ssh into a host server through VScode,
but it gave me a message about having a fingerprint. I'm wondering how to delete that ? I have tried to remove the known_host in the .ssh folder, but still having that message show up.
[image: has fingerprint]

Comment: If you press continue once, does it till prompt you to press this every time?

Comment: It doesnt work after saying continue. It gives  this error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60335069/vscode-remote-connection-error-the-process-tried-to-write-to-a-nonexistent-pipe

Answer (score 3):

When you connect over SSH, the server presents its host key to identify itself.  Unlike with TLS (used in HTTPS), which has certificate authorities to verify the remote host's key, typically in SSH the host key is unsigned, and so you are asked if you wish to trust it.

In this case, the fingerprint is telling you what the server's identity is and asking if you wish to trust it.  You should check the fingerprint with the people operating the server.  For example, if you were using GitHub (I happen to know you are not because of the fingerprint, but if you were), then you'd go to GitHub's website to check the fingerprint, and if it matches, you'd click “Continue”; otherwise, you'd click “Cancel” and investigate why the mismatch occurred.  Similarly, an in-house Git server should have some way of verifying this information.

Removing the `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file actually makes this problem worse.  That files contains the keys for known hosts, so if you've connected to that host before and you delete the file, you'll be prompted again.  You would want to avoid doing that without good cause.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvhQ7.png)

I was having the same issue I couldn't log in to the SSH server it showed my PC username instead of the SSH username which I gave when creating the Host.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file actually made the trick for me, because the ssh client will then automatically set up the fingerprint again for all hosts.

So, if you want to do this and don't care about having to type continue once for all your previously known ssh hosts, you can simply delete the `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file.

On Linux or MacOS open a terminal, on Windows open a Powershell, and type:

```bash
rm ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```