# Installing Python Extension for EC2 on VS Code gives error

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code, amazon-ec2

Ran a py file on EC2 via VS code, it took me to extensions & made me install python extension. Installed successfully. Then script ran too for a second. Then the SSH connection stops  working. When i reload, and try to connect to ssh again. it gets stuck on loading. after a few minutes the below error comes.

I have remove the vscode server to get rid of this error. But then the cycle restarts. I ssh  successfully, but then python extension has to be installed....error.

What am i doing wrong here?

```
[17:38:14.355] Using SSH config file "C:\config"
[17:38:14.356] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 1337 -F "C:\config" "9th_ec2" bash
[17:38:14.359] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[17:38:15.413] > ]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[17:38:15.413] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[17:57:47.197] > Connection reset by 3.110.108.203 port 22
> The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
[17:57:48.784] "install" terminal command done
[17:57:48.784] Install terminal quit with output: ]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exeConnection reset by 3.110.108.203 port 22
[17:57:48.785] Received install output: ]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exeConnection reset by 3.110.108.203 port 22
[17:57:48.786] Failed to parse remote port from server output
[17:57:48.786] Resolver error: Error: 
    at Function.Create (c:\Users\shivamanand\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.76.1\out\extension.js:1:586041)
    at Object.t.handleInstallOutput (c:\Users\shivamanand\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.76.1\out\extension.js:1:584693)
    at Object.t.tryInstall (c:\Users\shivamanand\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.76.1\out\extension.js:1:681846)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async c:\Users\shivamanand\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.76.1\out\extension.js:1:644486
    at async Object.t.withShowDetailsEvent (c:\Users\shivamanand\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.76.1\out\extension.js:1:647831)
    at async Object.t.resolve (c:\Users\shivamanand\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.76.1\out\extension.js:1:645565)
    at async c:\Users\shivamanand\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.76.1\out\extension.js:1:722872
[17:57:48.805] ------
```

Comment: Could you have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60335069/vscode-remote-connection-error-the-process-tried-to-write-to-a-nonexistent-pipe) page?